# How do you tell the CoqIde I want to use the apple keyboard “Command” for navigation of the proof?

Tags: coq

I want to have for my modifier navigation bar to have the "apple Command" keyboard button but I don't know how to tell my coqiderc what it is.

I tried:

```
modifier_for_navigation = "<Command>"
```

but it didn't work. How do I do this in a Mac?

---

reference cite: https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/Configuration-of-CoqIDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough rep for a comment, but this may or may not answer your question.

Have you tried using `<Primary>` instead of `<Command>`? It looks like that's what's used [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/8271b23dd0a26bba79c7d6dadd92d2329945675c/ide/MacOS/default_accel_map).

> (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/Navigation/Forward" "<Primary><Control>Down")

Comment: Why would you want to make this a comment, this **is the answer**. Thanks, sent you the acceptance ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

As User said use `<Primary>`. Here is the instructions I wrote for myself:

On Mac OS X, in `~/Library/Application\ Support/coq/` is where the file is, but do command:

```
vim ~/Library/Application\ Support/coq/coqiderc
```

(3) Edit the file `coqiderc` and make the following change:

|before | modifier_for_navigation = `"<Control>"` | 
|after | modifier_for_navigation = `"<Shift><Primary>"` |

---

Note:

`<Primary>` is the funny apple key button.

---

https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/Configuration-of-CoqIDE
[How do you tell the CoqIde I want to use the apple keyboard “Command” for navigation of the proof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464325/how-do-you-tell-the-coqide-i-want-to-use-the-apple-keyboard-command-for-naviga)